# Convert interface to RMI interface

Tags: java, interface, rmi, bytecode

I have an interface, for example:

```
interface MyService {
  String sayHello(Object who) throws ServiceException;
}
```

And now I need use this interface with RMI. Of course I can define another interface like:

```
interface MyService extends Remote{
  String sayHello(Object who) throws RemoteException;
}
```

and then adapt my implemention class to the RMI interface.

But I have hundreds interfaces to convert to RMI. Write hundreds classes with same logic is so boring and ugly.

So is there a simple way to use these interfaces in RMI?

Comment: @AJNeufeld I have hundurds interfaces. Convert all the interfaces is so ugly. Actually, I alrealdy have solution by myself, this question is just share my solution for others.

Comment: I remember a project called TRMI from almost two decades ago. It simply solved the problem by not requiring the interfaces to be changed, e.g. not needing them to inherit from `Remote`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is real scene in my work. And I used dynamic bytecode to do the hundurds work in one time.

First, here is my old code demo (without RMI).

```
class ServiceException extends Exception {
  public ServiceException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }
}

interface MyService {
  String sayHello(Object who) throws ServiceException;

  void throwIt() throws ServiceException;
}

class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  @Override
  public String sayHello(Object who) throws ServiceException {
    String hello = who.toString();
    System.out.println("Server said: " + hello);
    return "Hello! " + hello;
  }

  @Override
  public void throwIt() throws ServiceException {
    throw new ServiceException("throw in server");
  }
}
```

And I use Javassist to convert the interface to RMI interface:

```
  public static Class<? extends Remote> toRemoteInterface(Class<?> inter) throws Exception {
    return cache("toRemote", inter, () -> uncheck(() -> {
      ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
      CtClass cc = pool.getAndRename(inter.getName(), inter.getName() + "$RemoteVersion");
      cc.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC | cc.getModifiers());
      cc.addInterface(pool.get(Remote.class.getName()));
      for (CtMethod cm : cc.getMethods()) {
        cm.setExceptionTypes(new CtClass[] { pool.getCtClass(RemoteException.class.getName()) });
      }
      cc.writeFile();
      return cc.toClass();
    }));
  }
```

Then, use Cglib to convert between the remote object and the local object:

```
  public static <T> T fromRemote(Remote remote, Class<T> inter) throws Exception {
    Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
    e.setInterfaces(new Class[] { inter });
    e.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, proxy) -> {
      Method remoteMethod = remote.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
      try {
        return remoteMethod.invoke(remote, args);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Throwable targetException = ex.getTargetException();
        while (targetException instanceof RemoteException) {
          targetException = targetException.getCause();
        }
        throw targetException;
      }
    });
    return (T) e.create();
  }

  public static <T> Remote toRemote(T local, Class<T> inter) throws Exception {
    Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
    e.setSuperclass(UnicastRemoteObject.class);
    e.setInterfaces(new Class[] { toRemoteInterface(inter) });
    e.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, proxy) -> {
      Method targetMethod = local.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
      try {
        return targetMethod.invoke(local, args);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Throwable targetException = ex.getTargetException();
        throw new RemoteException(targetException.getMessage(), targetException);
      }
    });
    return (Remote) e.create();
  }
```

Now we can use the non-rmi interface and its implementation just like it is RMI interface:

```
  public static void startClient() throws Exception {
    String stringURL = "rmi://127.0.0.1/" + MyService.class.getName();
    toRemoteInterface(MyService.class);// define the Remote interface in client classloader
    MyService service = fromRemote(Naming.lookup(stringURL), MyService.class);
    String said = service.sayHello("Dean");
    System.out.println("Client heard: " + said);
    service.throwIt();
  }

  public static void startServer() throws Exception {
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    Remote remote = toRemote(new MyServiceImpl(), MyService.class);
    Naming.rebind(MyService.class.getName(), remote);
    System.out.println(remote);
    System.out.println(remote.getClass());
    System.out.println("Server started!");
  }
```

For complete code, [see this on github](https://github.com/XDean/Share/blob/master/src/main/java/xdean/share/rmi/javassist/ConvertRMI.java)